# What does パラパラ雨揺れる mean?

Tags: song-lyrics, onomatopoeia, subjects

> **パラパラ雨揺れてる**のに今僕たちには無関係

It is a part of a song called オオカミハート.

Does パラパラ describe a sound or a movement?
I don't understand what is shaking. Is it the rain that is shaking (雨は/が) or is it something, I think somebody, that is shaking because of the rain (omitted subject + 雨で/に)?

Can't they be separate sentences? "Pitter-patter. It's raining. Even though I'm shaking, now, that has nothing to do with us".

Comment: I guess the whole thing does not make much sense even to most native speakers. But パラパラ means sporadic raindrops - I'd say it's sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[パラパラ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9) is an onomatopoeia for light rain just as [ザーザー](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC) is for heavy rain. 雨がパラパラ降っている is a very common expression, so it definitely refers to rain. You can hear the パラパラ sound [here](https://pixta.jp/audio/tags/%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9?option%5Baudio_category%5D=se).

And I think we should simply parse that the subject of 揺れてる here is 雨. In this context, 今僕たちには無関係 is clearly about the rain, which is usually annoying. Of course nothing in the song suggests these people are on an unstable boat. 雨が揺れている is not a common expression at all, but I think this is a poetic way of describing some aspect of a rainfall, not a person. For example, they may be looking at the rain through a frosted glass.